# Read MOLCAS chemistry files to create color maps

Tags: python

My name is Ruben and I am seeking tips on how to improve/optimize these functions. I picked up Python last year and I am at a point at which I can code scripts to do what is needed, but as you will see I am for sure a beginner especially when it comes to parsing files.

This section of the Python script has the purpose of going into a long log file that is given by the ab initio computational chemistry program MOLCAS (included a cropped log file) and copies the Dipole values under the RASSI module section to 3 separate files:

```
XDIPOLE (MLTPL 1 COMPONENT 1 in log file), 
YDIPOLE (MLTPL 1 COMPONENT 2 in log file), 
ZDIPOLE (MLTPL 1 COMPONENT 3 in log file).
```

After doing so the next section of code also included here creates a color map that shows the dipole values in a more eye-friendly manner. The code as it stands does work however I have been able to optimize all the scripts except for these two tasks which I know are not the best approaches.

I am interested only in the values under `"PROPERTY: MLTPL  1"` I will include a copy of what the output files look like which are pretty straight forward especially when looking at a very small number of states.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import sys
import seaborn as sns
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def GetDipoleValuesAsArray(filename,string,delimiter):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        value=[]
        for line in fin:
            if string in line:
                option_value = (line.partition(delimiter)[2]).strip()
                value.append(option_value)
        return value

def ExecuteNoWrite(command):
    #>Executes to command line but does not print
    p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    p_status = p.wait()
    if p_status > 0:
        print("Errors found:: ", p_status)
        sys.exit()

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

# >Gets Dipoles found inside of <Project>.log "RASSI" Section.
#
def CopyXYZDipoles(filein, fileout, linestart, linestop, numberofstates):
    linestop2="PROPERTY: MLTPL  2"
    with open(filein, 'r') as fin:
        with open(fileout + "temp", 'w') as fout:
            copy = False
            for line in fin:
                if linestart in line:
                    copy = True
                    next(fin)
                    next(fin)
                    next(fin)
                elif "STATE" in line:
                    next(fin)
                elif linestop in line:
                    copy = False
                elif linestop2 in line:
                    copy = False
                elif copy:
                    fout.write(line)
    range_states = range(0, numberofstates, 1)
    with open(fileout, 'w') as fout:
        fout.write("\n")
        for states in range_states:
            states += 1
            string = " " + str(states) + " "
            value = GetDipoleValuesAsArray(fileout+"temp", string, "      ")
            fout.write(' '.join([str(f) for f in value]) + "\n")
        ExecuteNoWrite("rm " + fileout + "temp")

# >Calls "CopyXYZDipoles"
def GetDipolesFromLogFile(Project_Name,numberofstates):
    componentlist = list("123")

    for component in componentlist:
        component1 = str(int(float(component) + 1))
        if component == "1":
            dipolename = "X_DIPOLE"
        elif component == "2":
            dipolename = "Y_DIPOLE"
        elif component == "3":
            dipolename = "Z_DIPOLE"
        CopyXYZDipoles(Project_Name + ".log", dipolename,
                       "PROPERTY: MLTPL  1   COMPONENT:   " + component,
                       "PROPERTY: MLTPL  1   COMPONENT:   " + component1, numberofstates)
        print("Extracted " + dipolename)



# >Makes a color matrix of the Dipoles between each states
#
def Make_MU_HeatMap(directory):
    rows = file_len(directory + "/X_DIPOLE")
    cols = rows
    direction_list = list("XYZ")
    for direction in direction_list:
        with open(directory + "/" + direction + '_DIPOLE', 'r') as fin:
            data = []
            next(fin)
            for i in range(1, rows):
                data.append(list(map(float, fin.readline().split()[:cols])))
        df=pd.DataFrame(data)
        # mask = np.zeros_like(data)
        # mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True # cuts out upper triangular side of the matrix
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))
        cmap = sns.color_palette("coolwarm", as_cmap=True)
        sns.heatmap(
            df,  # The data to plot
            # mask=mask,  # Mask some cells
            cmap=cmap,  # What colors to plot the heatmap as
            annot=True,  # Should the values be plotted in the cells?
            vmax=1,  # The maximum value of the legend. All higher vals will be same color
            vmin=-1,  # The minimum value of the legend. All lower vals will be same color
            center=0,  # The center value of the legend. With divergent cmap, where white is
            square=True,  # Force cells to be square
            linewidths=.5,  # Width of lines that divide cells
            cbar_kws={"shrink": .5}  # Extra kwargs for the legend; in this case, shrink by 50%
        )
        f.savefig(directory + "/" + direction + '_DIPOLE_heatmap')

#!..Parameters
Project_Name = "CO2"
Number_of_States= 5

#!..Calls
GetDipolesFromLogFile(Project_Name, Number_of_States)
Make_MU_HeatMap(".")
```

These are the output files where the values are saved:

```
XDIPOLE
-----------------------

7.712938629E-14 -9.102311508E-13 -3.732978631E-01 -2.438713418E-15 -4.761724182E-14
-9.102311508E-13  9.679238374E-12  1.728909151E+00  9.858812476E-15 5.265071924E-15
-3.732978631E-01  1.728909151E+00 -9.364600903E-12 -1.572229977E-14 -1.101781051E-14
-2.438713418E-15  9.858812476E-15 -1.572229977E-14  5.212719145E-12 1.710295527E+00
-4.761724182E-14  5.265071924E-15 -1.101781051E-14  1.710295527E+00 -5.040856621E-12
-----------------------

YDIPOLE
-----------------------

4.074216029E-14  6.729178137E-15  4.369864581E-15 -7.306955227E-01 1.089101587E-12
6.729178137E-15 -1.952287317E-15  1.801795560E-15 -3.231487341E-01 -4.975377619E-13
4.369864581E-15  1.801795560E-15  3.519326344E-17  3.572170536E-13 -3.559337038E-01
-7.306955227E-01 -3.231487341E-01  3.572170536E-13 -3.847568714E-14 -1.913983826E-15
1.089101587E-12 -4.975377619E-13 -3.559337038E-01 -1.913983826E-15 4.386068916E-17
-----------------------

ZDIPOLE
-----------------------

-1.137579010E-16 -5.756682914E-18 -3.879122328E-19 -2.660126688E-06 -6.017214054E-17
-5.756682914E-18 -1.113544139E-16  1.103580246E-17 -1.173776231E-06 1.101877183E-18
-3.879122328E-19  1.103580246E-17 -6.831956398E-17  1.297128434E-18 -1.293133976E-06
-2.660126688E-06 -1.173776231E-06  1.297128434E-18 -1.120046885E-16 1.098611840E-17
-6.017214054E-17  1.101877183E-18 -1.293133976E-06  1.098611840E-17 -6.842153071E-17
-----------------------
```

These are the colored matrixes
[image: XDIPOLE COLOR MATRIX]
[image: YDIPOLE COLOR MATRIX]
[image: ZDIPOLE COLOR MATRIX]

This is a shortened log file: ( for unedited log file I added it to https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qP5nsAZ64SyEktTYXm4eMAqlNamuBoQq/view?usp=sharing )

```
()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()

                                               &RASSI

                                   only a single process is used
                       available to each process: 10 GB of memory, 1 thread?
                                             pid: 24875
()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()


      ********************************************************************************
      *                                                                              *
      *                             General data section                             *
      *                                                                              *
      ********************************************************************************
      
      
      
############################      
#...............        ##########

# ... Other parts of the long log file here. Skipping to Dipole section ...

#...............        ##########
############################


      ****************************************************************************************************
      *                                                                                                  *
      *                                   Spin-free properties section                                   *
      *                                                                                                  *
      ****************************************************************************************************


++ Matrix elements

  =========================================
   MATRIX ELEMENTS OF 1-ELECTRON OPERATORS
   FOR THE SPIN-FREE EIGENSTATES:
  =========================================
  (including nuclear contrib.)

  SELECTED PROPERTIES:
 MLTPL  0  1    MLTPL  1  1    MLTPL  1  2    MLTPL  1  3    MLTPL  2  1
 MLTPL  2  2    MLTPL  2  3    MLTPL  2  4    MLTPL  2  5    MLTPL  2  6
 VELOCITY  1    VELOCITY  2    VELOCITY  3    ANGMOM    1    ANGMOM    2
 ANGMOM    3    MLTPV  2  1    MLTPV  2  2    MLTPV  2  3    MLTPV  2  4
 MLTPV  2  5    MLTPV  2  6

 PROPERTY: MLTPL  0   COMPONENT:   1                        #This is not wanted
 ORIGIN:   0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00

  STATE          1                2                3                4

    1        1.200000000E+01 -2.194426650E-16  4.318101516E-18  1.330225916E-15
    2       -2.194426650E-16  1.200000000E+01 -8.386861199E-14  5.042296192E-17
    3        4.318101516E-18 -8.386861199E-14  1.200000000E+01 -8.220056120E-17
    4        1.330225916E-15  5.042296192E-17 -8.220056120E-17  1.200000000E+01
    5        2.926475414E-26  1.490676187E-27  6.588695814E-27 -1.246229307E-15

  STATE          5

    1        2.926475414E-26
    2        1.490676187E-27
    3        6.588695814E-27
    4       -1.246229307E-15
    5        1.200000000E+01

 PROPERTY: MLTPL  1   COMPONENT:   1                              #This is wanted
 ORIGIN:   0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00

  STATE          1                2                3                4

    1        7.712938629E-14 -9.102311508E-13 -3.732978631E-01 -2.438713418E-15
    2       -9.102311508E-13  9.679238374E-12  1.728909151E+00  9.858812476E-15
    3       -3.732978631E-01  1.728909151E+00 -9.364600903E-12 -1.572229977E-14
    4       -2.438713418E-15  9.858812476E-15 -1.572229977E-14  5.212719145E-12
    5       -4.761724182E-14  5.265071924E-15 -1.101781051E-14  1.710295527E+00

  STATE          5

    1       -4.761724182E-14
    2        5.265071924E-15
    3       -1.101781051E-14
    4        1.710295527E+00
    5       -5.040856621E-12

 PROPERTY: MLTPL  1   COMPONENT:   2                        #This is wanted
 ORIGIN:   0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00

  STATE          1                2                3                4

    1        4.074216029E-14  6.729178137E-15  4.369864581E-15 -7.306955227E-01
    2        6.729178137E-15 -1.952287317E-15  1.801795560E-15 -3.231487341E-01
    3        4.369864581E-15  1.801795560E-15  3.519326344E-17  3.572170536E-13
    4       -7.306955227E-01 -3.231487341E-01  3.572170536E-13 -3.847568714E-14
    5        1.089101587E-12 -4.975377619E-13 -3.559337038E-01 -1.913983826E-15

  STATE          5

    1        1.089101587E-12
    2       -4.975377619E-13
    3       -3.559337038E-01
    4       -1.913983826E-15
    5        4.386068916E-17

 PROPERTY: MLTPL  1   COMPONENT:   3                        #This is wanted
 ORIGIN:   0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00

  STATE          1                2                3                4

    1       -1.137579010E-16 -5.756682914E-18 -3.879122328E-19 -2.660126688E-06
    2       -5.756682914E-18 -1.113544139E-16  1.103580246E-17 -1.173776231E-06
    3       -3.879122328E-19  1.103580246E-17 -6.831956398E-17  1.297128434E-18
    4       -2.660126688E-06 -1.173776231E-06  1.297128434E-18 -1.120046885E-16
    5       -6.017214054E-17  1.101877183E-18 -1.293133976E-06  1.098611840E-17

  STATE          5

    1       -6.017214054E-17
    2        1.101877183E-18
    3       -1.293133976E-06
    4        1.098611840E-17
    5       -6.842153071E-17

 PROPERTY: MLTPL  2   COMPONENT:   1                        #This is not wanted
 ORIGIN:   0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00

  STATE          1                2                3                4

    1        4.823310421E+01 -1.805369316E+00  4.783430444E-12  7.632822170E-14
    2       -1.805369316E+00  4.482222024E+01 -9.951086369E-13 -4.665853905E-14
    3        4.783430444E-12 -9.951086369E-13  4.458050931E+01 -7.566061281E-15
    4        7.632822170E-14 -4.665853905E-14 -7.566061281E-15  4.585650178E+01
    5       -9.358570459E-17  1.592285998E-16  1.279473824E-17 -1.616419414E-13

  STATE          5

    1       -9.358570459E-17
    2        1.592285998E-16
    3        1.279473824E-17
    4       -1.616419414E-13
    5        4.577125639E+01

 PROPERTY: MLTPL  2   COMPONENT:   2                        #This is not wanted
 ORIGIN:   0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00

  STATE          1                2                3                4

    1       -2.192419537E-16 -2.411741231E-16 -2.314343136E-17 -2.063236807E-12
    2       -2.411741231E-16 -1.096619443E-16 -1.500648083E-17  1.065273015E-13
    3       -2.314343136E-17 -1.500648083E-17  6.945394753E-17 -2.689810760E-25
    4       -2.063236807E-12  1.065273015E-13 -2.689810760E-25 -1.257444004E-15
    5       -1.431227599E+00  6.493368077E-02 -1.623715429E-13 -3.989299446E-14

  STATE          5

    1       -1.431227599E+00
    2        6.493368077E-02
    3       -1.623715429E-13
    4       -3.989299446E-14
    5       -1.454288070E-15

 PROPERTY: MLTPL  2   COMPONENT:   3                        #This is not wanted
 ORIGIN:   0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00

  STATE          1                2                3                4

    1       -7.138286176E-17 -3.053047924E-18 -5.733640991E-17 -1.369977170E-16
    2       -3.053047924E-18 -7.650874504E-17  5.043306125E-17 -7.885876738E-17
    3       -5.733640991E-17  5.043306125E-17 -4.059241581E-17  8.831450537E-29
    4       -1.369977170E-16 -7.885876738E-17  8.831450537E-29 -7.209622042E-17
    5       -5.208466495E-06  2.363040658E-07 -8.562577275E-17  4.752354755E-17

  STATE          5

    1       -5.208466495E-06
    2        2.363040658E-07
    3       -8.562577275E-17
    4        4.752354755E-17
    5       -3.593758270E-17

 PROPERTY: MLTPL  2   COMPONENT:   4                        #This is not wanted
 
 ############################      
#...............        ##########

# ... Keeps going after this and so on however I am only currently wantin go the make files for the MLTPL  1  COMONENTS:  {1,2,3} ...

#...............        ##########
############################
```

Thank you so much even for reading this question and any help or suggestion will help me.

Comment: How big are the log files?  Read in the whole file and search for key strings like "PROPERTY: MLTPL  1   COMPONENT:" rather than process the file one line at a time.

Comment: Hi @Reinderien thank you for replying and I apologize for the delayed response, I added the missing functions I was calling.

Comment: @RootTwo the log files vary a lot but they can be a few thousand lines depending on the printing level selected. So you suggest reading the entire file first then looking for the specific string?

Comment: @RubenFernandez a reviewer should be able to copy the data and code from the question, run it, and get the desired output.  You want the reviewer to spend time on improving your code, not wasting time figuring out missing imports or undefined functions.

Comment: @RootTwo Hi I just fixed the previous issues, and you are right, I do apologize for wasting your time. The script now will produce the desired results using the complete log file I attached (added it as a google drive link).  I would also add the rest of the code but I just corrected the above script to be self-contained the rest would not be related to the output as they handle other files. I took out any references to the output directory location so it should be run in the same directory in which the log file is found. Please let me know of any updates.

Comment: @Reinderien Hi I realized that I could only notify one user at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for completing your question! I'm glad you did, because this was interesting to me.

Here is a list of things that I've suggested you change in your application:

- Put your constant parameters at the top of the file in all-caps
- Use snake_case for your variable and method names
- Use type hints, as I've shown below for your method signatures
- Change your `get_dipoles` method to look for a prefix, instead of looking for a substring; and use a simple `split()` instead of worrying about an explicitly specified whitespace delimiter
- Do not not not include an "execute no write" and do not call "rm", for so many reasons. Just call `remove`.
- Do not include a `file_len`. This is not the best way to count lines, but also just don't count lines. Leave that to Pandas when it reads the data frame.
- Do not use a temp file. Your data are extremely small - they should stay in memory. My quick fix is to use `StringIO` so that it still looks and smells like a file even though it's in memory; but you should probably just represent this as an in-memory list of strings. Even if you did have to use a temp file, use `tempfile` module instead of rolling your own.
- Don't include a blank line at the beginning of your matrix files.
- In your `join`, do not use an inner list and drop your redundant `str` cast.
- Simplify your `componentlist` iteration. Just enumerate over an `XYZ` string of names. Do not have an `if` based on your iteration index.
- Install and use a linter such as that built into PyCharm.
- Use `pathlib` for path management and concatenation.
- Do not save a space-delimited matrix. Use a standard `csv` instead, and load this in one call to `pd.read_csv`.
- Add a main guard at the bottom.

### Suggested

```
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Parameters
PROJECT_NAME = 'CO2'
N_STATES = 5


def get_dipole_values(temp_file: StringIO, prefix: str) -> Iterable[str]:
    for line in temp_file:
        if line.startswith(prefix):
            yield from line[len(prefix):].split()


def copy_xyz_dipoles(
    filename_in: str,
    filename_out: str,
    line_start: str,
    line_stop: str,
    n_states: int,
):
    """
    Gets Dipoles found inside of <Project>.log "RASSI" Section.
    """

    linestop2 = 'PROPERTY: MLTPL  2'

    with StringIO() as ftemp:
        with open(filename_in) as fin:
            copy = False

            for line in fin:
                if line_start in line:
                    copy = True
                    next(fin)
                    next(fin)
                    next(fin)
                elif 'STATE' in line:
                    next(fin)
                elif line_stop in line:
                    copy = False
                elif linestop2 in line:
                    copy = False
                elif copy:
                    ftemp.write(line)

        with open(filename_out, 'w') as fout:
            for state in range(1, n_states + 1):
                prefix = f'    {state} '
                ftemp.seek(0)
                values = get_dipole_values(ftemp, prefix)
                fout.write(','.join(values) + '\n')


def read_dipoles(project_name: str, n_states: int):
    """
    Calls "copy_xyz_dipoles"
    """

    for component, dim in enumerate('XYZ', 1):
        dipole_name = f'{dim}_DIPOLE.csv'
        copy_xyz_dipoles(project_name + '.log', dipole_name,
                         f'PROPERTY: MLTPL  1   COMPONENT:   {component}',
                         f'PROPERTY: MLTPL  1   COMPONENT:   {component + 1}',
                         n_states)
        print('Extracted', dipole_name)


def make_mu_heatmap(directory: Path):
    """Makes a color matrix of the Dipoles between each states"""

    for direction in 'XYZ':
        df = pd.read_csv(directory / (direction + '_DIPOLE.csv'), header=None)
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))
        cmap = sns.color_palette('coolwarm', as_cmap=True)

        sns.heatmap(
            df,  # The data to plot
            cmap=cmap,  # What colors to plot the heatmap as
            annot=True,  # Should the values be plotted in the cells?
            vmax=1,  # The maximum value of the legend. All higher vals will be same color
            vmin=-1,  # The minimum value of the legend. All lower vals will be same color
            center=0,  # The center value of the legend. With divergent cmap, where white is
            square=True,  # Force cells to be square
            linewidths=.5,  # Width of lines that divide cells
            cbar_kws={'shrink': .5}  # Extra kwargs for the legend; in this case, shrink by 50%
        )

        f.savefig(directory / (direction + '_DIPOLE_heatmap'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_dipoles(PROJECT_NAME, N_STATES)
    make_mu_heatmap(Path('.'))
```

Here is a slightly longer version that:

- classifies the project and each component
- detects the number of states, rather than having that hard-coded
- is more careful in parsing the matrix definitions in the log file, using `read_csv` in whitespace-delimited mode
- Keeps the (very, very small) dataframes in memory rather than forcing a disk round-trip for plotting
- Plots X, Y and Z in one triple-subplot figure for better spatial interpretation

```
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from typing import Iterable

from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.colors import Colormap
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Component:
    NAMES = 'XYZ'
    COLORMAP: Colormap = sns.color_palette('coolwarm', as_cmap=True)

    def __init__(self, section: str):
        *_, component, body = section.split(maxsplit=3)
        self.index = int(component)
        self.name = self.NAMES[self.index - 1]
        self.df = self._parse(body)

    @classmethod
    def _parse(cls, body: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        colsets = [
            cls._str_to_df(colset)
            for colset in cls._colset_strings(body)
        ]
        without_state = (
            df.drop('STATE', 1)
            for df in colsets
        )

        return pd.concat(
            (colsets[0].STATE, *without_state),
            axis=1,
        )

    @staticmethod
    def _colset_strings(body: str) -> Iterable[str]:
        first_col = 'STATE'
        start = body.find(first_col)
        while start != -1:
            end = body.find(first_col, start + len(first_col))
            yield body[start:end]
            start = end

    @staticmethod
    def _str_to_df(body: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        with StringIO(body) as f:
            return pd.read_csv(f, sep=r'\s+')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def without_state(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return self.df.drop('STATE', axis=1)

    def write_csv(self, path: Path, bare: bool = True):
        if bare:
            self.without_state.to_csv(path, index=False, header=False)
        else:
            self.df.to_csv(path, index=False)

    def mu_heatmap(self, ax: Axes) -> Axes:
        ax.set_title(self.name)

        return sns.heatmap(
            self.without_state,  # The data to plot
            ax=ax,               # Axes to draw on
            cmap=self.COLORMAP,  # What colors to plot the heatmap as
            annot=True,          # Should the values be plotted in the cells?
            # The maximum value of the legend. All higher vals will be same color
            vmax=1,
            # The minimum value of the legend. All lower vals will be same color
            vmin=-1,
            # The center value of the legend. With divergent cmap, where white is
            center=0,
            square=True,    # Force cells to be square
            linewidths=.5,  # Width of lines that divide cells
            # Extra kwargs for the legend; in this case, shrink by 50%
            cbar_kws={'shrink': .5},
        )


class DipolesProject:
    def __init__(self, log_path: str):
        self.components = tuple(self._parse(log_path))

    @staticmethod
    def _parse(log_path: str):
        with open(log_path) as f:
            body = f.read()

        start_i = body.find('PROPERTY: MLTPL  1 ')
        end_i = body.find('PROPERTY: MLTPL  2 ', start_i)
        body = body[start_i: end_i]
        sections = body.split('PROPERTY: MLTPL')[1:]

        for section in sections:
            yield Component(section)

    def write_csvs(
        self,
        directory: str = '.',
        suffix: str = '_DIPOLE.csv',
        bare: bool = True,
    ):
        directory = Path(directory)
        for component in self.components:
            component.write_csv(directory / (component.name + suffix), bare)

    def get_mu_heatmaps(self) -> Figure:
        fig, ((z, x), (y, unused)) = plt.subplots(
            2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row',
            figsize=(10, 10),
        )
        unused.remove()

        for ax, component in zip((x, y, z), self.components):
            component.mu_heatmap(ax)

        return fig


def main():
    project = DipolesProject('CO2.log')
    project.write_csvs()
    fig = project.get_mu_heatmaps()
    fig.savefig('dipole-heatmap.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The result of the plot is:

[image: triple subplot]

By far the slowest part of the program is now saving the figure itself; everything before `savefig` executes "instantly".

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to say thank you for your helpful comments at the beginning of your answer. To this day I am still using them. I did not complete all the changes to this specific project but have taken them with me going forward. Best, Ruben

Comment: @RubenFernandez Great to hear! Keep posting if you have anything else to review.